# Javascript for multi use fade text not working

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on some simple "READ MORE" fade text elements but have some trouble to get the script to work.

```
var box = document.querySelector('.readmorebox');
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');

for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){

    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        box.classList.toggle('open');

    });
}
```

The first fade text element works, but none of the following ones.

This is the html code I use:

```
    <div class="readmorebox">
        <p class="readmoretext">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <button class="arrow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="color:#3e4044"></i></button>
        <div class="readmoreboxshadow"></div>
    </div>
```

Working with IDs should be the last option to go with. Can someone out there please help me with this.

Comment: What _" first fade text element"_? What _following ones"_?

Comment: `box` is always the same element. What do you expect to happen with that?

Comment: Your code is far from complete. It simply doesn't reproduce what you say it does.